# Why it is very likely to see Chinese characters when I view a random UTF-8 webpage as UTF-16?

Tags: html, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Out of curiosity, I chose UTF-16 in the Encoding menu of a random English webpage to see what happens (on Chrome: Tools -> Encoding -> Unicode (UTF-16LE). What interested me is that almost all of the mojibake I see are Chinese characters (and some integral signs).

Are there any statistical reasons for seeing Chinese characters when switching from ASCII/UTF-8 English to UTF-16? Are the random non-Chinese special characters from HTML tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the smallest unit in UTF-16 is two bytes long, the first byte of most "low" characters like Latin starts with a `NUL` byte: `00 xx`. Since normal content does not typically contain `NUL` bytes, it's virtually impossible to hit Latin characters when interpreting random byte sequences as UTF-16. Most bytes of UTF-8 encoded content will be somewhere in the lower middle, like say `46 6F`. And that happens to be where many Asian languages are situated in UTF-16, and since Chinese is a ginormous block you're very likely to hit it.

Answer (score 2):

Most english characters are ASCII coded in the `[0x40-0x5a]` hex range. If you transcode UTF-8 to UTF-16, will have most of your characters in the range `[0x4040-0x5a5a]`, that aparently maps to Chinese chars

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Raul Andres as long as you view ASCII or UTF-8 that contains just ASCII characters as utf-16. However you might not view chinese characters anymore if your utf-8 content contains thai, hebrew or other languages that result in 2-byte, 3-byte or 4-byte sequences in utf-8.